# How do you get the router name to use in a template inside a for navigation loop using Aurelia Framework

Tags: aurelia

I need to get the router.name defined in the routes.

Code

```
 <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" data=${row.name}
 </li>
```

The code above does not get the route name.  I know all of the information I need is in the NavModel but I don't know how to access it in my above example using a for loop in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close there. What you're looking for is:

```
${row.config.name}
```

You can see the full route meta-data available by logging it out to the console in the `app.js` view-model:

[image]

This is also useful for if you what to include anything from the route settings in your nav.